# this.p is undefined jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have an interesting issue.  I have done this on multiple pages with multiple grids.  The first grid works fine the second grid in this case fails to load.  and give the following error:

this.p is undefined

...sArray(i)){P=true;h="last";U=f}else{i=[i];P=false}this.each(function(){var D=i.l... line 140 jquery.jqGrid.min.js

The user doble clicks on a row and that sets some variables and then calls the function locationGrid().

Like I said this has worked for me multiple times in the past, however on this page it fails.  I have double checked and I am getting data back as shown below:

{"d":"{\"total\":1,\"page\":0,\"records\":1,\"rows\":[{\"invPartLocId\":1053,\"inventoryMasterId\":5,\"location\":null,\"itemType\":\"S\",\"currentQanity\":1,\"adjustedQauntity\":0,\"newLocationQty\":0,\"deptCode\":\"1401 \"}]}"}

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    function locationGrid() {
        $('#invLocAdjustGrid').jqgrid({
            height: 290,
            loadui: "block",
            datatype: function (rdata) { getLocationData(rdata); },
            colNames: ['invPartID', 'locationPartID', 'Loctaion', 'Type', 'Current QTY', 'Adjusted QTY', 'New Location QTY', 'Dept. Code'],
            colModel: [
                    { name: 'invPartLocId', width: 2, sortable: false, editable: false, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'inventoryMasterId', width: 2, sortable: false, editable: false, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'location', width: 250, editable: false, sortable: false },
                    { name: 'itemType', width: 120, editable: false, sortable: false, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'currentQanity', width: 50, editable: false, sortable: false },
                    { name: 'adjustedQauntity', width: 50, editable: false, sortable: false },
                    { name: 'newLocationQty ', width: 50, editable: false, sortable: false },
                    { name: 'deptCode', width: 50, editable: false, sortable: false }
                ],
           pager: jQuery('#rptCodesPager'),
            viewrecords: true,
            width: 890,
            gridComplete: function () {
                $('#load_invLocAdjustGrid').hide();
                $(this).prop('p').loadui = 'enable';
                $('#lui_invLocAdjustGrid').hide();

            },
            afterInsertRow: function (rowid, aData) {

            },
            ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
                var myID = $('#invLocAdjustGrid').getCell(rowid, 'invPartLocId');
                Ldclicked(myID);
            }
        });
    }
    function getLocationData(rdata) {
        var theID = tempID;
        tempID = "";
        var myDTO = { 'id': theID };
        var toPass = JSON.stringify(myDTO);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "INV_Inventory_Adjustment.aspx/getInventoryLocationById",
            data: toPass,
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                if (textStatus == "success")
                    ReceivedLocationData(JSON.parse(getMain(data)).rows);
            },
            error: function (data, textStatus) { alert('An error has occured retrieving data!'); }
        });
    }
    function ReceivedLocationData(data) {
        var thegrid = $('#invLocAdjustGrid');
        var isGood = data.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < isGood; i++) {
                thegrid.addRowData(i + 1, data[i]);


            }
    }
```

Comment: you should use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` to see the place with the error more clear. Moreover you should include code which call `locationGrid`. I think that there are understanding problem. The `locationGrid` must be called **only once**.

Comment: I switched to using jquery.jqGrid.src.js, the failure is at line 2818 
ni = t.p.rownumbers===true ? 1 :0;

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but your code is buggy. Moreover I recommend you to rewrite the whole code and I try to explain why.

The first important error is that you use `$('#invLocAdjustGrid').jqgrid({...});` in the `locationGrid` instead of `$('#invLocAdjustGrid').jqGrid({...});`. JavaScript is case sensitive, so it's very important to use `jqGrid` instead of `jqgrid`.

Next problem exist because you use some variables and functions `tempID`, `Ldclicked` and `getMain` which you not defined in the posted code.

After making minimal changes [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RussellWalters.htm) works. I commented only "POST" to use HTTP GET because I get the JSON directly from the file and have no active components on the wed server.

One more problem which you clear have is that your server code serialize the results **twice**. Typically one have the problem because of wrong usage of ASMX WebMethods. One should *not* convert the object to JSON manually. Instead of that one need just return the object itself. Because of the problem the `d` property of the JSON are not the object itself and is a string which should be one more time be parsed:

```json
{
    "d": "{\"total\":1,\"page\":0,\"records\":1,\"rows\":[{\"invPartLocId\":1053,\"inventoryMasterId\":5,\"location\":null,\"itemType\":\"S\",\"currentQanity\":1,\"adjustedQauntity\":0,\"newLocationQty\":0,\"deptCode\":\"1401 \"}]}"
}
```

Even such wrong formatted data can be read by jqGrid **without** usage `datatype` as function. Moreover you should always use `gridview: true` and never use `afterInsertRow` and almost never use `addRowData`. The modified code can be about the following:

```js
var tempID = "abc";
$('#invLocAdjustGrid').jqGrid({
    url: "INV_Inventory_Adjustment.aspx/getInventoryLocationById",
    mtype: "POST",
    datatype: "json",
    postData: {
        id: function () { return tempID; } // ??? I don't know which data should be send
    },
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    serializeRowData: function (data) {
        return JSON.stringify(data);
    },
    beforeProcessing: function (data) {
        $.extend (true, data, $.parseJSON(data.d));
    },
    jsonReader: {repeatitems: false},
    loadonce: true,
    colNames: ['invPartID', 'locationPartID', 'Loctaion', 'Type', 'Current QTY', 'Adjusted QTY', 'New Location QTY', 'Dept. Code'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'invPartLocId', width: 2, key: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'inventoryMasterId', width: 2, hidden: true },
        { name: 'location', width: 250 },
        { name: 'itemType', width: 120, align: 'center' },
        { name: 'currentQanity' },
        { name: 'adjustedQauntity' },
        { name: 'newLocationQty ' },
        { name: 'deptCode' }
    ],
    cmTemplate: {sortable: false, width: 50},
    pager: '#rptCodesPager',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    loadui: "block",
    height: 290,
    width: 890,
    ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
        //Ldclicked(rowid);
    }
});
```

[The next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RussellWalters1.htm) demonstrate that the code work. I included in the demo the option `loadonce: true` which can be helpful for you too.